# Convergence in $L^1$ implies Convergence in measure using Chebyshev's Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of Lebesgue integrable functions that converges to $f$ in $L^1$. Then, I have to show that $\{f_n\}$ converges in measure.

Here is my approach:

So Claim: $\mu(x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|\geq\epsilon) \to 0$

for any $\epsilon >0$, by Chebyshev's Inequality, we have

Case 1:
 Consider $\mu(x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|> \epsilon)<\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int{|f_n(x)-f(x)|d\mu} \to0$ (as $f_n \to f$ in $L^1)$

Case 2: Consider $\mu(x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\epsilon)=\mu(x:-\epsilon +f(x)\leq f_n(x)\leq\epsilon+f(x)) \to 0(???)$ for any arbitrary $\epsilon$.

I am not sure about Case 2.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Not sure why do you need case $2$. If you proved that $\mu(x: |f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon)\to 0$ for any $\epsilon>0$ then you proved convergence in measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not really any reason to have case 2, because Chebyshev's inequality also works with $\le$ replacing $<$. If you're dead set on using it, then you haven't got the setup quite right (your first equality is wrong). The relevant estimate would be that

$$\mu\{x : g(x) = \lambda\} = \frac 1 {\lambda} \int_{\{x : g(x) = \lambda\}} g\, d\mu \le \frac{1}{\lambda} \int g \, d\mu$$
for positive $g$.

---

Alternatively, notice that

$$\mu\{|f_n - f| \ge \epsilon\} \le \mu\left\{|f_n - f| > \frac{\epsilon}{2}\right\}$$

and apply Case $1$.